# Gtkmm3: Getting a signal when clicking on a row in TreeView

Tags: c++, treeview, gtkmm

I have this code:

```
Glib::RefPtr<Gtk::TreeSelection> clSelection = treeview.get_selection();
clSelection.signal_changed().connect( sigc::mem_fun(*this, &MyClass::treeview_clicked) );
```

And get this error on compile with g++:

```
‘class Glib::RefPtr<Gtk::TreeSelection>’ has no member named ‘signal_changed’
```

I've looked everywhere and I don't seem to be missing anything. Why does it say that signal_changed() doesn't exist when it's in the documentation? Is there another way I can go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it should be:

```
clSelection->signal_changed().connect( sigc::mem_fun(*this, &MyClass::treeview_clicked) );
```